# How to implement the auto differentiation for prims op in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am learning some core Pytorch concepts. I can understand the backwards of some general operations, such as matrix multiplication. However, for some torch prims operations, such as `torch.real`, how to implement its auto differentiation, i.e backwards in the pytorch. If you can point me to the code in Pytorch, that would be super helpful.
Thanks!